# ClassCastException: jbpm workflow is failing on last task/node after workflow diagram updated

Tags: java, jboss, drools, jbpm, bpmn

After changing jbpm workflow diagram , old running process (which was completed till (endNode-1) node using old diagram) is failing at the last step while completing using jbpm new diagram.

**Example :- 0th HumanTask => 1st HumanTask => 2nd HumanTask => 3rd HumanTask => 4th HumanTask**

0,1,2,3 HumanTask completed using old diagram
4th HumanTask trying to complete using new jbpm diagram, but giving below error

Note:- in new diagram i have made 1st and 2nd task as subtask. i have tried other cases like completed 0/1 with old rest with new diagram, completed 0/1/2 with old rest with new diagram etc, i am able to complete rest of the HumanTasks with new diagram. **i am getting issue only when 0/1/2/3 completed by old diagram and last node is completed using new diagram.**

````
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.jbpm.workflow.core.node.Join cannot be cast to class org.jbpm.workflow.core.node.HumanTaskNode (org.jbpm.workflow.core.node.Join and org.jbpm.workflow.core.node.HumanTaskNode are in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @5d5160e6)
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.HumanTaskNodeInstance.getHumanTaskNode(HumanTaskNodeInstance.java:33) ~[jbpm-flow-7.29.0.Final.jar:7.29.0.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.HumanTaskNodeInstance.triggerCompleted(HumanTaskNodeInstance.java:86) ~[jbpm-flow-7.29.0.Final.jar:7.29.0.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.workItemCompleted(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:451) ~[jbpm-flow-7.29.0.Final.jar:7.29.0.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.signalEvent(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:421) ~[jbpm-flow-7.29.0.Final.jar:7.29.0.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.signalEvent(WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.java:616) ~[jbpm-flow-7.29.0.Final.jar:7.29.0.Final]
    at org.drools.persistence.jpa.processinstance.JPAWorkItemManager.completeWorkItem(JPAWorkItemManager.java:167) ~[drools-persistence-jpa-7.29.0.Final.jar:7.29.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.command.runtime.process.CompleteWorkItemCommand.execute(CompleteWorkItemCommand.java:75) ~[drools-core-7.29.0.Final.jar:7.29.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.command.runtime.process.CompleteWorkItemCommand.execute(CompleteWorkItemCommand.java:35) ~[drools-core-7.29.0.Final.jar:7.29.0.Final]```
````